# How do I direct different URL's with optional capture groups to the same Handler?

Tags: python, tornado

I'm trying to make a site such that

`example.com/mx/about` -> Mexico About Page
`example.com/us/about` -> US About Page
`example.com/about` -> International About Page

In the handlers, I can have

```
(r'/([A-Za-z]{2})/about/?', AboutPageHandler),
```

Which captures the two letter country code, but if the URL does not have the two letter country code, instead of directing to the AboutPageHandler, the server will 404.

Is there a way to have the two letter country code optional and redirect to the country code-less URL if it's not present? Or do I have to do this to all my handlers

```
(r'/([A-Za-z]{2})/about/?', AboutPageHandler),
(r'/about/?', AboutPageHandler),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make the relvant parts of the regex optional, by placing a `?` after them:

```
import tornado.web
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

class AboutPageHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, lang=None):
        self.write("HI {}\n".format(str(lang)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tornado.web.Application([
       #(r'/([A-Za-z]{2})/about/?', AboutPageHandler)       # Old, busted regex
        (r'/(?:([A-Za-z]{2})/)?about/?', AboutPageHandler)  # New, hot regex
        ])  
    app.listen(8888)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```

As you can see, we've taken the piece of your regex that match the country code and its trailing slash, and put it inside an optional (using the `?` in `(stuff)?about`), non-capturing (using `(?:stuff)`) group. Now, when you try connecting to either page:

```
dan@dantop:~> curl localhost:8888/about
HI None

oreild1@dantop:~> curl localhost:8888/about
HI mx
```

Success.

Comment: This regex will also match "//about" or "/mxabout" since the two optional parts are separate.  Instead, you can wrap the whole thing in an optional non-capturing group: `r'/(?:([A-Za-z]{2})/)?/about/?'`

Comment: There's actually a small typo in the regex @BenDarnell included (an extra `/` before `about`), so don't copy it directly from his comment. I corrected it in my edit, so copy that instead.

Comment: Love the new, hot regex. Works like a charm. Thanks!